# How to establish the primary and secondary monitors via MS Windows Registry

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, windows-registry

I would like to establish the **primary** and **secondary** monitors via MS Windows Registry and later to change their number.

I mean to make **secondary** monitor as **primary** and vise versa.

I have tried to search here but no joy. Any clue?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}]

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0000]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000320
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000258
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:0000003c
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:fffffce0
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0000\Mon00000001]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000320
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000258
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:0000003c
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0000\Mon00000002]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000320
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000258
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:0000003c
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0000\Mon12345678]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000320
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000258
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0001]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000400
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000300
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:0000003c
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0001\Mon00000001]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000320
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000258
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:0000003c
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{E3A95856-CD0B-4A7C-9749-393140073ECE}\0001\Mon00000002]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSettings.BitsPerPel"=dword:00000020
"DefaultSettings.XResolution"=dword:00000320
"DefaultSettings.YResolution"=dword:00000258
"DefaultSettings.VRefresh"=dword:0000003c
"DefaultSettings.Flags"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.XPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.YPanning"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.Orientation"=dword:00000000
"DefaultSettings.FixedOutput"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeX"=dword:00000000
"Attach.RelativeY"=dword:00000000
```